# Jsoup selector for one of the element

Tags: java, css, xpath, jsoup

Recently I have started learning jsuop with java where i need to parse html page for properties of an element. i have took a same page as below . in that there is image when i spy through Selenium IDE i got a property as

```
 xpath=(//img[@alt='Moto G: Mobile'])[2]
```

as jsoup does not support xpath. how to convert this in to CSS Selctor for jsoup.

i have tried

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.flipkart.com/").get();
Elements t3 = doc.select("img[alt='Moto G: Mobile']:nth-of-type(2)");
System.out.println(t3.size());
System.out.println(t3.get(0));
```

but getting

```
0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

is there any better way to handle these kind of properties using jsoup.

can any body help me .

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is not your query. The image you are searching is dynamically added by JavaScript and not part of the HTML you’ve fetched.

Comment: thnk you for your reply so how to handle such type of element properties using jsoup.when i gone through other sites when there are two elements with same properties this kind of situation is coming ,is there any other better way to handle these elements.  .as this is xpath any other method to find element using xpath. once again thamks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand your question. Or you didn’t understand my answer. Jsoup is not a browser. It won’t execute JavaScript. It just fetches plain HTML. Jsoup works with the same content you can see if you disable JavaScript in your browser or display the source-code.